# TinyGPS++ Question about gps.encode(ss.read())

Tags: arduino-ide, library, tinygps

I am trying to make an oled gps display, however when looking at multiple examples and other people's code, I am seeing that people are using different methods. I see some code that has `gps.encode(ss.read());` and other people use `if gps.encode(ss.read())`. I am confused on why this is. Also, people either use `.isUpdated`, or `.isValid`, when checking for location/speed, etc. On the TinyGPS++ page it talks about these, but does not say what should be used for certain applications.

Comment: it's not really about `what should be used for certain application` ... it is about `what does it do?` ... the library takes serial input data and assembles it into a GPS data structure ... certain "flags" are set as the GPS data is assembled, if data has changed ... if a certain function is useful in your program, then use it ... there is no specific use for any of the functions ... so your best start is to learn what `ss.read()` does, then what `gps.encode()` does, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

From http://arduiniana.org/libraries/tinygpsplus/

**Validity, Update status, and Age**
You can examine an object’s value at any time, but unless TinyGPS++ has recently been fed from the GPS, it should not be considered valid and up-to-date. The **isValid()** method will tell you whether the object contains any valid data and is safe to query.

Similarly, **isUpdated()** indicates whether the object’s value has been updated (not necessarily changed) since the last time you queried it.

Lastly, if you want to know how stale an object’s data is, call its **age()** method, which returns the number of milliseconds since its last update. If this returns a value greater than 1500 or so, it may be a sign of a problem like a lost fix.